# Fresh install of Windows 8 on Zenbook Prime with UEFI

Tags: windows, boot, installation, uefi, external-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If USB is not listed in BIOS as a boot option, does that mean the machine can’t boot from USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/507111/if-usb-is-not-listed-in-bios-as-a-boot-option-does-that-mean-the-machine-cant)
>   [Asus UEFI/BIOS options - How to boot from DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-uefi-bios-options-how-to-boot-from-dvd)

I have purchased a new Asus Zenbook Prime (UX31A) with Windows 8 preinstalled. To prepare a clean install without any bloatware I wanted to create an image of the whole SSD, because it seems there is no application to create some Recovery DVDs because there exists a complete recovery partition.

To create an image I have a connected an external CD drive to boot a Live CD, however there is no way to actually boot from it (maybe UEFI prevents this?).

What do you suggest - how should I boot from my CD to create an image?

Comment: See whether [Asus single boot option](http://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-single-boot-option) and [If USB is not listed in BIOS as a boot option, does that mean the machine can't boot from USB?](http://superuser.com/questions/507111/if-usb-is-not-listed-in-bios-as-a-boot-option-does-that-mean-the-machine-cant) help.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a recovery media creator?  There should be an AI Recovery application that will allow you to create media.

Comment: @ernie: No there is none - I was surprised, too.

Comment: @Karan: Your second link helped me, I will post an answer!

Answer (score 0):

With Karan's link to my question I was able to boot from CD. First in the Setup I have **disabled** *Security > Secure Boot Control*, I have **disabled** *Boot > Fast Boot* and **enabled** *Boot > Launch CSM* for legacy support. Now it boots from CD!