# How to enable Fastboot again on BIOS?

Tags: windows-8, boot, ssd, bios, uefi

I have recently replaced the hard drive of my Asus Zenbook UX303LN with an SSD drive and managed to do a clean install of Windows 8 thanks to the link below:
[If USB is not listed in BIOS as a boot option, does that mean the machine can't boot from USB?](https://superuser.com/questions/507111/if-usb-is-not-listed-in-bios-as-a-boot-option-does-that-mean-the-machine-cant)

Now that I have succesfully installed Windows 8, my question is: how do I enable again Secure boot and fast boot?

Everytime I go to the UEFI and hit the F9 button to load the default settings, my computer boots on the UEFI rather than the SSD. Additionally, it seems like no booting drive is listed at all.
The only way I have to boot on the SSD is to disable secure boot and fast boot and enable the Launch CMS.

Thanks guys for reading my request.

Comment: Are you saying your unable to boot into Windows?

Comment: I am able to boot into Windows only in these conditions: Fast boot [Disabled], Launch CMS [Enabled], Secure Boot [Disabled].

I want to get back the default configuration and thus be able to boot into Windows with these conditions: Fast boot [Enabled], Launch CMS [Disabled], Secure Boot [Enabled].

But when I do so, I boot into the UEFI :/

Comment: What BIOS Version are you running?

Comment: The lastest: BIOS 204
I downloaded it from the Asus website: http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=UX303LN&p=3&s=666

Comment: If you have CMS enabled and secure boot disabled then you didn't install Windows on a GPT partition which means there is likely no EFI partition on the drive

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Are you suggesting that I should format and reinstall Windows and creating the EFI partition during the install or can I create the EFI partition afterwards?

Comment: If you reinstall Windows 8 make sure the boot priority is set to "uefi only". That makes sure you boot Windows in UEFI mode and not legacy, or else it wont a GPT table.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks guys for your help!
As you've stated, I didn't install Windows 8 properly the first time and was missing the EFI partition.

The reason is that I didn't use a UEFI bootable USB drive.

I followed this tutorial to create the right bootable USB drive: http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/15458-uefi-bootable-usb-flash-drive-create-windows.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: -1  Can you explain clearly what the connection is between the title of this question,  "how-to-enable-fastboot-again-on-bios" and your answer?  No doubt you mean UEFI rather than BIOS(since nowadays laptops have a UEFI not a BIOS).  But what's the connection between the fastboot option in the UEFI, and a usb stick and windows?  And if you were trying to say an option was there and now isn't then you should include screenshots of both cases.